# Get Reverse relations object in rest framework

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

How do I get the object from the reverse relation in serializers.py?

I have a model like this

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     content = models.TextField()

     def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

class Category(models.Model):
     post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='category')   
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=70, unique=False)

     def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

And from the [Django Rest Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#reverse-relations), I can access the category directly through the related name and this is my serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
        class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content','category')
```

The problem is the the view only return the category post id:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Post title 1", 
            "content": "test content..blah blah blah", 
            "category": [
                1 
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

How can I get the category name and slug??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *related_name* will only return id's, and this is not wrong at all. If you want the full representation, you will also need to add a serialized version of each child object in your parent. Like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

So you first need to have a CategorySerializer, and then you must add the relationship in the PostSerializer. All parameters are optional. [Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#example) is a small example.

P.S. : I suggest using 'categories' as related_name, since you can have more than just one.

Comment: Tried this, and it give me `'Post' object has no attribute 'category'` error.

Comment: Have you also changed the related_name to categories?

Comment: Oh yes, it was the problem and it works now!! Thanks.